# In AWS WebSocket API (API Gateway), can I send a message to the client in the $connect route?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

When my lambda gets ivoked due to $connect route getting invoked, can I safely send a message to the connection id at this point. Or is the connection not yet fully established? Is it a better idea to use a HTTP response header?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to as you will have the client's connectionID. [The docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-route-keys-connect-disconnect.html#apigateway-websocket-api-routes-about-connect) say the connection is established when your integration execution completes.

Comment: But it hasn't completed yet. I'm right smack in the middle of executing the integration :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear so:

> Until execution of the integration associated with the $connect route
> is completed, **the upgrade request is pending and the actual connection
> will not be established.** If the $connect request fails (e.g., due to
> AuthN/AuthZ failure or an integration failure), the connection will
> not be made.

Through my experimentation I'm unable to send messages back and also the highlighted line above suggests that the connection isn't completely established during the CONNECT phase. My guess is that it can still be rejected for failed auth, throttle, or whatever reasons. Because of this, it's not technically ready.  At least this is how I'm interpreting it...

[Source docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-route-keys-connect-disconnect.html#apigateway-websocket-api-routes-about-connect)